# Stop Facebook using GPS

Tags: gps, facebook

I have set location to off but I can see it is still trying to use GPS from the icon in the top left corner.

Where in the settings can I switch this off for Facebook only? Despite Messenger location servvices being set to Off, everytime I open the app it tries to get a GPS lock.

I am running the latest stock Nexus 4 firmware and Android 4.2.

Comment: Are you sure it's facebook app? What happens when you remove it?

Comment: AFAIK, the location services option in FB settings is for "Facebook Messenger" only. The GPS notification appears for me whenever I go to pick a location, or "Check in", regardless of whether I have "Messenger location services" enabled or disabled in FB settings. But otherwise the GPS notification does not seem to appear for me (Nexus 4, FB 2.2.1).

Comment: Go into Settings > Location Access, Look for Location Sources, uncheck GPS Satellites and Wifi&Mobile network location.

Comment: @t0mm13b: But won't this disable location services for the entire phone?

Comment: @w3d Yes and the OP asked "*Where in the settings can I switch this off?*" despite having it turned off from within Facebook app... just saying :)

Comment: @w3d As soon as I open the application, the GPS tries to get a lock.

Comment: @t0mm13b Sorry I will rephrase, I want this off for Facebook only.

Comment: Are you rooted?

Comment: The only thing I can think off is to selectively disable the GPS/Request Location permissions in the app itself - think CM has that feature...

Comment: Is it possible that a "Facebook App" (installed in FB itself) is requesting location services?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to do this in the app settings. You can turn it off for messaging, and you can always turn off the alerts for "friends that are nearby", but the check-in functionality needs to call the GPS. And let's not forget that they are working toward creating targeted ads, which in many cases require knowing (approximately) where you are.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK [PDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.privacy.pdroid&hl=en) is the best solution. (Except you need to be rooted) You could even set a custom GPS location per app.

[Permission Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer&feature=related_apps) is a good alternative.